# Select different field from same table field - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

My MySQL skills are very basic, so what i want to get is the name of the team 1 and the team 2 of the table matches from the table teams, in a single SELECT statement (if possible). I have a statement but I only get the name of the team 1 in team 2 I get the same name as the team 1

**Teams Table**

```
---------------------------------------
- team_id  - team_title  - team_image -
---------------------------------------
-        1 - Brazil      - br.png     -
-        2 - Russia      - ru.png     -
-        3 - Spain       - es.png     -
---------------------------------------
```

**Matches Table**

```
------------------------------------------
- match_id  - match_team1  - match_team2 -
------------------------------------------
-         1 -            2 -           3 -
-         2 -            1 -           2 -
-         3 -            3 -           1 -
------------------------------------------
```

**Function**

```
function get_all_matches($connect)
{

    $sentence = $connect->prepare("
    SELECT matches.*
         , teams.team_title 
      FROM matches
         , teams 
     WHERE matches.match_team1 = teams.team_id 
     ORDER 
        BY matches.match_id DESC
        "); 
    $sentence->execute();
    return $sentence->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: You can use the same table twice with different alias: `SELECT t1.team_title AS team1title, t2.team_title AS team2title FROM teams AS t1, teams AS t2, matches AS m WHERE m.match_team1 = t1.team_id AND m.match_team2 = t2.team_id`

Comment: We stopped using comma-style joins ca. 1992. Come. JOIN us. Then join the teams table twice - once for each team. Give it a different alias each time.

Comment: So you're expecting to get something back like *Brazil vs Russia* for `match_id = 2` ?

Comment: @CD001 Yes, i want to get this result (Brazil vs Russia)

Comment: `SELECT
matches.match_id,
t1.team_id,
t1.team_name,
t2.team_id,
t2.team_name

FROM matches

INNER JOIN teams AS t1
 ON t1.team_id = matches.match_team1

INNER JOIN teams AS t2
 ON t2.team_id = matches.match_team2` as @RomanHocke said, it's about the aliases, I'd probably write it something like this but the principle is the same.

Comment: @RomanHocke Resolved, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two joins, one for each team name you want to retrieve.

Also, note the implicit joins (having more than one table in the `from` clause) have been considered deprecated for quite some time, and you should probably use the modern explicit `join` clause instead:

```sql
SELECT   m.*,
         t1.team_title AS team_1_title,
         t2.team_title AS team_2_title
FROM     matches m
JOIN     teams t1 ON m.match_team1 = t1.team_id 
JOIN     teams t2 ON m.match_team2 = t2.team_id 
ORDER BY m.match_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried somthing like

```
 Select A.match_team1, t1.team_title,  
       A.match_team2, t2.team_title   
 FROM matches A                       
      left outer join teams t2        
        on A.match_team2 = t2.team_id,
      teams T1                        
 WHERE A.match_team1 = t1.team_id
```

I am not familiar with MySql, but joins should be supported I guess.